# SQL reformat a linked list (a list of locations: nodes -> edges)

Tags: sql-server

Hopefully you can help me out by providing aide with a bit of syntax.

I'm trying to reformat this:

```
id1 id2     pathType   location  
1   1   start   AlgonacPark
2   1   move    DuckLakePark
3   1   move    ClearLakePark
4   1   finish  GrandLakePark
5   2   start   CraigLakePark
6   2   finish  HayesPark
```

into this:

```
1   NULL    AlgonacPark
1   AlgonacPark DuckLakePark
1   DuckLakePark    ClearLakePark
1   ClearLakePark   GrandLakePark
1   GrandLakePark   NULL
2   NULL    CraigLakePark
2   CraigLakePark   HayesPark
2   HayesPark   NULL
```

The logic is relatively straightforward...

(a.)  create a set of groups using id2

For each group,

(b.)  if pathType = start -> (id2, NULL, location)

(c1.)  make an ordered list of the locations, using 'id1' to order the list.

(c2.)  output the list in pairs using a loop -->  (id2, location1, location2)

Example:

2 locations:  (1,2) --> (1,2)

3 locations:  (1,2,3) --> (1,2), (2,3)

4 locations:  (1,2,3,4) --> (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)

n locations where (n>1): (1,...,n) --> (1,2), ... , (n-1,n)

(d.)  if pathType = finish -> (id2, location, NULL)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query.it will work properly .

```
 WITH TEMP
 AS
 (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1) AS ID , *
 FROM LOCATION
 )
 SELECT A.ID1, A.ID2 , B.LOCATION , A.LOCATION 
 FROM TEMP AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMP AS B ON A.ID -1 = B.ID AND A.ID2 = B.ID2
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT A.ID1,A.ID2 , A.LOCATION , NULL
 FROM TEMP AS A 
 WHERE PATHTYPE = 'FINISH'
 ORDER BY ID1
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e80e6/5/0)

Comment: Very nice.  Works exactly as anticipated.

Comment: Rewriting this with a full join would allow you to avoid UNION.

Comment: yes sure , you can try . we always try to find good solution of the problem .